# Make a image for website hyperlink

Tags: html, image, web, hyperlink

I want to use a image as a hyperlink in my website. I know what code is used for this.
But here is a problem in the image.

How can I make img like this which is in the form of cirlce I see many software but I can not find any software which make a image in the form of cirlce. they are all make a image in the form of square. If you know any one please tell me...

Comment: What do you mean? You want to make a circular element with a image on it, or a image with a transparent region so it is just a circle?

Comment: I want to make a circular image not a transparent image.

Comment: Yes, but you can make a circular image by erasing all parts of it that are outside of a circle. Imagine a pencil-drawn rectangle which is filled. Now pick up a imaginary eraser and erase parts of it so it becomes a circle. In the computer, this process is called "masking".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once had this issue and used this.

```
<img src="circle.png" width="145" height="126"  usemap="#mymap">  
<map name="mymap">  
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,50" href="circle.htm">  
</map>
```

You will have to use a png image to display a circle (remaining is transparent). On the image use map feature of html. It worked to the fullest in my scenario. :)

To learn more about map follow the below link.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Hope it will help you.

**Edit as per your request for an arrow:-**

Yes, You can make a arrow. use shape="poly" for that. and use the coords="x1,y1,x2,y2,..,xn,yn"

Let me know if you have more issue in it. :)

Comment: Only simple question if I want to make a arrow shape image can I do that.
I know I can make remaning part of img transparent but not forget it is the part of image. I need only arrow, onlyyy arrow

Comment: Yes sure.. you can do it.. use shape="poly" for that. Simple.
:)

Comment: @user3316709 I have modified my answer for this.. Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to use a image as a hyperlink in my website. I know what code is used for this.

The same way as you make any other content into a link. You have a `<img>` element and you wrap a `<a>` around it.

> How can I make img like this which is in the form of cirlce

You can't per se. I'm not aware of any image format that has a non-rectangular canvas.

You can set the around outside a circle to use the transparent "color" (in image formats which support transparency, such as PNG).

Alternatively, in an HTML document, you can use the CSS `border-radius` property (set to 50% of the image size) to crop the corners of the image.